Prevent first comment on questions to be posted by OP
When a new question is posted, sometimes the OP will add a comment to the newly posted question, especially on the Staging Ground where the OP hasn't much experience yet. However, these comments are not a response to a clarification question from others. There are at least two categories of such comments:

The comments contain important information for the question like "this is my code: ..." or "I'm using browser XY". This information should be in the question itself and not part of a comment (especially in Staging Ground since comments aren't copied over when the question gets published).
The comments contain only meta-information or fluff like "Can someone help me?" or "Why the downvote?".

In either case, these comments shouldn't exists in the first place. Either the information is important and part of the question/problem and should be edited into the question itself, or the comment should be deleted.
I propose a feature where the OP is not able to post a comment when there are no previous comments from others to respond to. This forces the user to edit their question to add the additional information (and to learn that you can in fact edit your question).
I have played around with the following data explorer query to get an idea of the kinds of initial comments by OPs (see permalink) so you can check such comments by yourself:
SELECT
  TOP(200) c2.Id AS CommentId,
  --c2.PostId,
  c2.UserId AS CommentUserId,
  c2.Text AS CommentText,
  c2.CreationDate AS CommentDate,
  p.CreationDate AS QuestionDate,
  p.Id as [Post Link],
  DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.CreationDate, c2.CreationDate) AS TimeBetweenQuestionAndComment
FROM
  Comments c2
JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      MIN(c.Id) AS FirstPostId
    FROM
      Comments c
    GROUP BY
      c.PostId
  ) AS fp
  ON
    fp.FirstPostId = c2.Id
JOIN
  Posts p ON p.Id = c2.PostId
WHERE
  c2.CreationDate >= '2024-01-01' AND
  p.PostTypeId = 1 AND
  c2.UserId = p.OwnerUserId AND
  NOT c2.Text LIKE '@%' AND
  DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.CreationDate, c2.CreationDate) < 24*60*60
--ORDER BY
--  CommentDate DESC

The result contains some false positives like responses to deleted comments, especially from the deleted "is a duplicate" comment. You can adjust the WHERE conditions as needed; I only wanted to limit the execution time of the query.
The main question here is if there is a legit reason why the OP should add a comment instead of editing the question. If there is none, then the OP shouldn't be able to add a comment because such comments shouldn't exist.
This restriction should only be applied to initial comments by the OP. When there is a comment by someone else, then the OP should obviously be allowed to add comments.

Spammers also do this a lot, sometimes posting multiple spam comments

On the one hand, having less unnecessary comments would be nice, on the other hand I am afraid that this additional restriction would only cause more frustration and confusion among new users. I wouldn't be surprised that some of those comments (like why the downvotes) would end up being edited in the question. Overall, I think that such feature would be more trouble than it is worth.

"Why the downvotes?" can easily be an indication that downvoters should have left comments to which the OP could have responded.

@Nanigashi Check out this FAQ.

Thanks for the interesting SQL query. However, it is not obvious to me that the majority of the comments is clearly invalid.

@Anerdw, that faq is about required comments, so it's not exactly on point. If there's something wrong with the questions, people should leave comments, but I agree that they should not be required. It isn't wrong to seek guidance. A picture may be worth a thousand words, but a downvote isn't.

@Nanigashi A comment of 'Why the downvotes' isn't adding anything to the situation though. People will comment or they won't. A comment asking for guidance is as likely to put people off by making the OP look 'pushy' as it is to actually solicit feedback.

@user1937198, I disagree. An OP who solicits constructive feedback is adding to the interaction. It's the downvoter who is not adding anything by dropping a bomb and walking away. That's not on the OP.

@Nanigashi as a downvoter, that's not how it's going to be read. The assumption is the OP wants feedback. That's implicit in the site social contract, not wanting feedback is disrespectful. Thinking your question is specially deserving of feedback beyond the default is special treatment and being pushy. At a bare minimum I would expect an attempt to try and identify why you are getting down voted to even consider it engagement.

@Nanigashi stackoverflow has a very blunt etiquette,  and its generally expected that anything on the site is trying to convey something that isn't already conveyed. Therefore, asking for why downvotes is either not adding information (inappropriate for etiquette) or implies an expectation beyond the normal (pushy).

@user1937198, since the expectation is that the OP wants feedback, isn't it a violation of etiquette not to provide it? Sure, there's no requirement to be nice and provide it, but isn't that why etiquette exists (in any context)? Contracts (even social ones) involve a commitment from both parties.

@Nanigashi Let's keep it focused on this Q&A's subject matter. This is only about whether or not the asker should be commenting things like "why the downvotes." Since these comments are unlikely to prompt downvoters to add a comment if they weren't going to already, whether or not downvoters should be downvoting is immaterial - even if it's a "violation of etiquette," this feature request is unlikely to affect that.

“This restriction should only be apply to initial comments by the OP. When there is a comment by someone else, then the OP should obviously be allowed to add comments.” – it’s not like comments should be ordinarily addressed by editing the question instead of replying to them…

Well, part of the problem, at least in the 'Staging Ground', is that Askers get encouraged to post 2 Comments to get the 'Eager Learner' Badge... (I would rather have that they get a Badge for reading thoroughly the [ask] Help-page, like they get for taking the [Tour], than posting some Comment(s) that either belong(s) as Edit(s) to their Question, or is/are usually completely useless...)

staying on the how-to-ask page for a minute, or scrolling down on it, shouldn't grant anyone a badge. passing a quiz should. all these badges are cute but gamification requires a delicate touch to the balancing of the game, not handing them out like participation trophies. nobody can pretend that these imaginary internet points mean nothing when this entire thing is a game and we're the product. this thing is making money for someone based on our altruism/boredom and we get a pat on the head and that's all we get. it's a free energy hack running on our energy.

@ChristophRackwitz Yep, agreed of course (about the Badges), but in the 'Staging Ground', I need to ask 80% of the Askers to take the 'Tour' and probably 90% to read the 'How-to-Ask' page, and for the 'Tour', the 'Informed' Badge at least tells me (as a Reviewer) that they've "had a look at it", so that Badge is still "a bit useful" for Reviewers...

I agree with Dalija's comment that this could result in more frustration and unnecessary edits. However, I can see this as a useful feature if it was to be implemented as a pop-up, like what we have for self-answering, to notify OP about purpose of comments section and availability of editing their question.

On the one hand, having less unnecessary comments would be nice, on the other hand I am afraid that this additional restriction would only cause more frustration and confusion among new users.
There are already many restrictions around comments and other actions, and I don't see how adding more restrictions in the area that does not really cause any harm (comments under their own questions, regardless of their nature) would benefit new users.
I also wouldn't be surprised that some of those comments (like asking "why the downvotes") would end up being edited in the question. Overall, I think that such feature would be more trouble than it is worth.
Another answer suggests that this could be implemented as a pop-up to inform users what the answers are for. While this would at least partially solve some issues, especially if users pay attention and read what is written, too many users don't read that much and pop-ups are often just annoying distraction that many close without reading.
Maybe if there would be just an initial guidance about comments when someone tries to post their first comment, but which wouldn't prevent them from posting the comment.

I think your assumption that the vast majority of users close popups without reading them even when they don't know its content, even when it's clearly a reaction to an action on their part, is very pessimistic. I think most users would read a short popup and at least the beginning of a longer popup the first time they see it, and even if only a fraction do, as long as it prevents some bad comments, the feature is productive. If your concern is that the popup would worsen the experience for users who know this already, that can be addressed e.g. by only showing it once per user.

@Annonymus New users are overwhelmed by everything. Especially if they have also gone through account creation at that time. It is not uncommon that people close some pop-ups quickly without reading them properly. We see that every day, users simply don't follow guidelines that are literally under their nose. Preventing bad comments in such narrow scenario is not at all very important and there are far more important things developers could work on.

The motivating issue is prevalent in Staging Ground. I haven't observed it as a noticeable problem outside of SG. I'd suggest to limit this just for SG if it's to be done. Or maybe some site design should be done in SG or in general to make it more obvious to the asker that they should edit clarifications into their question. That's the more general issue- also prevalent in SG and outside of SG.

I have a (I believe) legitimate use case for self-first-comments, which you did mention in your question, but did not address: useful meta information.
I've used self-comments in the past for things like "I'm not sure if this Q belongs to X.SE or Y.SE, I went with X because of blah, but feel free to correct me".
I feel like the question should be limited to the actual question — a future reader coming here from google to find the answer to the same question should not find the question polluted by discussion specific to the user who asked the question, or to the platform (SE) imo.
I agree with the improper uses of self-comments you've described, but not that all self-comments are improper. Hence I agree that a "warning" approach would be productive, but not disallowing them completely.

Those comments are noise, though...

Are you arguing that a coment like the example I made is not productive? If you aren't, it has to happen somewhere, and it's better for that place to be the comments than the question. In fact I would argue that comments are specifically the place meant for meta discussion of the question itself. If you are, could you explain? I called it useful because (assuming somebody replies) it educates users on how to ask good questions (which imo is something the site does rather badly). Removing this opportunity means reducing overall question quality. Do you believe its harm is greater than its use?

They're not useful. If the question is off-topic, then the question should be closed, no comment necessary.

There is no point in preemptively asking if a question is off-topic. If one posts something, it's assumed the poster believed it was on-topic. Otherwise, they wouldn't have posted it, right? If other users disagree, they'll vote or comment as required. No comment from the poster would be required in that sense. There is no need for an "invitation" to give feedback and/or use the site's features.

I too have found (very) occasional use for meta self-comments.  Here, Annonymus is suggesting a case where the comment explains why they thought the question is on topic, which I would want to read before deciding whether to downvote.  Another use is to acknowledge relationships to other Q+A when doing so doesn't make sense in the body (although it usually does).  The OP's proposal would ban even legitimate meta self-commentary, which while rare, does exist.  The suggestion by M--, to merely advise against it, seems much better.

If you aren't sure if the post is on-topic on the site you plan to post on then ask on their meta site first about if the question would be. If it isn't then very likely you'll also get suggestions on where could ask it. Posting a comment to state you think the post is off-topic could more likely attract swifter closure (and downvotes) due to people possibly believing you posted the question in the wrong place intentionally.
